# What is the GNOME Classic Monospace font?

Tags: gnome, fonts, cinnamon

I am moving to Cinnamon from GNOME Classic. I would like to bring the terminal font from GNOME. In Cinnamon the fixed width system font is also called Monospace but it looks different. Is there another name for the GNOME default terminal font?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `fc-match` to see which fonts match that pattern:

```
# fc-match "Monospace"
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
```

To see the whole priority list matching that pattern, use:

```
fc-match --sort "Monospace"
```

Reference: `man fc-match`

> **fc-match** matches pattern (empty pattern by default)  using  the 
>   normal
>          fontconfig matching rules to find the best font available. If **--sort** is
>          given, the sorted list of best matching fonts is displayed.  The  **--all**
>          option  works like **--sort** except that no pruning is done on the list of
>          fonts.

Source: [How to get a valid font name on linux system which can be used in .Xresources config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186428/how-to-get-a-valid-font-name-on-linux-system-which-can-be-used-in-xresources-co/14186633#14186633)